# How to relate subquery to outer query for update

Tags: mysql

Hello I have a database that looks something like this.

```
uniqueid    description       name         phonenumber
66370         SALES       John_Doe_Cell      555-5555
87296         SALES       John_Doe_Home      555-4444
66786       ACCOUNTING    Jane_Doe_Cell      555-3333
67897       ACCOUNTING    Jane_Doe_Home      555-2222
```

I am trying to run a query that will pull `phonenumber` for `%_Cell` and transfer that phone number to `%_Home`. So for example in the table above I need John_Doe_Cell phonenumber to be put into John_Doe_Home phonenumber, same goes for Jane_Doe_Cell and Jane_Doe_Home.

The queue I have thus far is the following but I do not feel like it will work. I need to be able to pass the Name it finds during the lookup to be applied to `%_Home` so that it updates the correct name with the corrent phone number.

```
UPDATE `some_table` SET phonenumber=(SELECT phonenumber WHERE `name` LIKE '%_Cell')
WHERE queue_name LIKE '%_Home'
```

Comment: I didnt run it yet but I did run just the portion in parenthesis, the issue I am afraid of is that since (SELECT phonenumber WHERE name LIKE '%_Cell')  returns Jane_Doe_Cell and John_Doe_Cell so it wont set Jane_Doe_Cell or John_Doe_Cell properly

Comment: You are having this issue because you really need to separate columns for 1 for the home phone and 1 for the cell phone. then it would be a simple update.

Answer (score 0):

Your schema is odd, to say the least, and could stand to be normalized, but to answer your question *as asked*, your issue is two-fold.

1. The sub-select returns more than one result for the update, and
2. the sub-select result is not related to the UPDATE set.

From your data, let's try out the subselect:

```
> SELECT phonenumber WHERE `name` LIKE '%_Cell';
+-------------+
| phonenumber |
+-------------+
| 555-5555    |
| 555-3333    |
+-------------+
```

To update then, you need to both get your subselect to return 1 row, and you'll want to relate it to the outer query's row set.  For example, this would work to give you one row for the subselect, but will give you incorrect data:

```
> UPDATE `some_table` AS upd SET phonenumber = (
    SELECT phonenumber
    FROM `some_table` AS inn
    WHERE
        `name` LIKE '%_Cell'
    LIMIT 1
  )
  WHERE queue_name LIKE '%_Home';
```

What row will that inner query pick for each outer row?  (Hint: try it and see, perhaps in a transaction so that you can rollback the results.)  To connect the inner and outer query, I'm guessing this is what you might want:

```
> UPDATE `some_table` AS upd SET phonenumber = (
    SELECT phonenumber
    FROM `some_table` AS inn
    WHERE
        `name` LIKE '%_Cell'
    AND inn.description = upd.description
  )
  WHERE queue_name LIKE '%_Home';
```

Note the `inn.description = upd.description`, which given the question's provided data, is the only piece of data that uniquely connects the rows you want.

Very generally (with definite exceptions), joining on text columns and other non-indexed fields is indicative of poor schema design.  If this is for a serious project, I highly suggest you look into schema normalization to at least 3<sup>rd</sup> normal form.  (I'll leave googling as an excercise to the reader.)